# gnuplot histogram with Perl: How to put values on top of bars

Tags: perl, gnuplot

How can the following gnuplot plot can be generate using Perl ?
(I need a histogram where under each bar I will write the difference between that column and the column on its right side, with the same data)

The problem is that I didn't figure out how to put numbers under the bars, using Perl.

[image]

This is the code of gnuplot:

```
reset

set terminal png 

set output 'StackOverflow.png'

set style fill solid 1.00

set style histogram clustered gap 1

set style data histograms

set yrange [0:120]

set xtics norangelimit font ",8"

set ytics norangelimit font ",8"

set key font ",8"
set key width -8

xoffset=0.17
yoffset=0.03

plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1) with histogram title "Parameter 1", \
     '' u 3 with histogram title "Parameter 2", \
     '' u 0:2:4 with labels offset -0.9,0.5 title "", \
     '' u 0:3:5 with labels offset 2.0,0.5 title ""
```

Currently I have generated the following using Perl:
[image]

And this is the Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Chart::Gnuplot;

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    output => 'plotStyle_19.png',
    yrange => [0, 120],
    bg     => {
        color   => "#c9c9ff",
        density => 0.2,
    },
);

my @x = qw( A B C D );
my $h1 = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => \@x,
    ydata => [99, 97, 97, 95],
    title => "1st data set",
    color => "purple",
    fill  => {density => 0.2},
    style => "histograms",
);

my $h2 = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => \@x,
    ydata => [9, 10, 13, 15],
    title => "2nd data set",
    color => "dark-green",
    fill  => {density => 0.2},
    style => "histograms",

);

$chart->plot2d($h1, $h2);
```

Comment: See the [datastrings demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/datastrings.5.gnu).

Comment: @SinanÜnür how can I add this feature to the Perl code?

Comment: In similar cases I just form necessary variables and put them in "here document". It seems that this perl package has pretty poor capacities.

Comment: I believe this feature is not supported yet, by Chart::Gnuplot;